# how do i know if element in array is there?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

So I have an array in my C program

```
Node *array;
array = (Node*)malloc(53*sizeof(Node));

if(array[5] is empty)
 //Fill array index with element
```

How do I test if element is there or not? I've tried if(array[5] == NULL) but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: `array[5]` is of type `Node`, and not a pointer to `Node`. It is not comparable to `NULL`

Comment: `array` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: after the `malloc` call, there are 53 nodes. There's no such thing as a node being "there or not".

Comment: You need to at least initialise before you check in C. They're there, but they could contain pretty much anything if you don't initialise them.
[And please don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried `if(array[5] == NULL)` but it keeps giving me an error.

This does not work for two reasons:

- `malloc` does not initialize the memory returned to your program. You are responsible for setting memory to zero, and
- `Node` is not a pointer type, so you do not know if a `Node` is valid or not without knowing the structure of `Node` itself

You could switch to a double-pointer `Node **array`, and allocate it like this:

```
array = (Node**)malloc(53*sizeof(Node*));
memset(array, 0, 53*sizeof(Node*));
```

However, this means that you would have to `array` as an array of pointers, with `malloc`s of individual elements and so on.

If you want an array of `Node` structures, use a separate array of markers that indicate that a particular element is used or not.

Answer (score 1):

All of the elements in the array exist. There's no way to check whether an element exists, because elements can't not exist.

If you want to have some concept of a "nonexistent element", you have to make it yourself. A straightforward way to implement this would be to have a field in `Node` which stores whether the node "exists". You'd set that field to false in every `Node` after allocating them, and you'd set it to true whenever you want the node to "exist".

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the memory with a sentinel value, such as zero, and then check whether `array[5]` only contains that value. E.g.:

```
#define UNINITIALIZED 0

Node *array = calloc(53, sizeof(Node)); // don't cast malloc and friends!
Node null_node;
memset(&null_node, UNINITIALIZED, sizeof(Node));

if(memcmp(&array[5], &null_node, sizeof(Node)) == 0)
    // …
```

Just make sure a valid `Node` instance can never equal to that sentinel value.

This is more efficient than dasblinkenlight's solution, because it involves an additional indirection. However, if a safe sentinel value cannot be found, and adding an `int uninitialized` (or similar) flag field to `Node` is not possible, the extra pointer is necessary, unless you store the information about which elements are initialized somewhere else.

Comment: Although this assumes that a zeroed Node isn't a valid/useful value, of course... which it very well could be.

Comment: Yes. In that case there could be some other value used to indicate "not initialized".

Comment: Perhaps you could add a brief mention of using a sentinel value to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think using c++ in such cases is better because then you can use default constructors to initialize. 
In your case, if you want to check if Node was 'initialized' or not, simply do a calloc and then check value of some integer var.

```
struct Node {
   //set to 1 if not empty
   char emptyFlag;
   initialize() {

        emptyFlag = 1;

        //other stuff 
   }
}

Node *array;
array = (Node*)calloc(53 , sizeof(Node));

if(array[5].emptyFlag == 0)
 //initialize array[5]
```

Comment: Recommending C++ when the OP indicates they're using C is the same as recommending that they use Javascript.